# Google AdWords showing more clicks than keywords clicked?

Tags: google-ads

Why does AdWords sometimes show for example a total of 185 clicks, and in the keyword tab it shows a total of 12.

Most of the time, if I manually add up the clicks on each keyword and the "total" clicks, they will be the same amount. But today there are many clicks unaccounted for.

[image]

My bidding strategy was "Maximize Clicks" - does that have anything to do with it? Sorry this problem is hard to Google for, couldn't find anything specifically related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are clicks unassigned to a keyword in the data, then it's likely that you have display expansion on. This shows text ads on the display network. This would result in clicks that aren't associated with any keywords. You can see if you got any clicks from display by clicking the arrow next to the Total: Account label at the bottom of the report. It'll show a row for Total: Search Keywords on Display.

Also, you may have DSAs running (Dynamic Search Ads).  These use machine learning to match your website with search terms, so those clicks wouldn't be associated with a keyword. You can check these by looking for any ad groups which use DSAs.

If you're referring to the *Search Terms* report not having all click associated with the data given, this is because Google isn't giving users all of the data about which search terms trigger your ads. This may be down to user privacy settings, but I do understand that it's frustrating. Google at least list the unreported data at the bottom under "Other search terms". For some of the accounts I run, these unreported search terms account for over 50% of clicks and conversions on the account.